# Can $y=\frac{e^\frac{t^4}{12}}{e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}}$ be simplified?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Can $y=\frac{e^\frac{t^4}{12}}{e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}}$ be simplified?**

So, I'm working on a problem and I encounter this problem instead. For some reason, the way it looks is intimidating. So this is how I'm tackling it:

I multiply the bottom denominator by 4 and obtain:

$$y=\frac{e^\frac{t^4}{12}}{e^{\frac{4t^3}{12}}}$$

so i'm wondering can I divide even though the exponents are different?
If I can, then I would just get:

$$y=4e^t$$

but i'm not sure.

Comment: $\frac{m^a}{m^b}=m^{a-b}$

Comment: OH YEAH! !!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, recall that $\dfrac{e^a}{e^b} = e^{a-b}$.

Comment: A neat answer. +1!

Answer (score 7):

$$\frac{e^{\frac{t^4}{12}}}{e^{\frac{t^3}{3}}}=e^{\frac{t^4}{12}-\frac{t^3}{3}}=...$$

Comment: may be the downvoters could explain ;-)

Comment: i thought that was right o.o

Comment: What a roller-coaster! And @CSil, there's nothing wrong with this answer. You are still left to calculate the difference in the exponent, but now you know the property at work.